# Trying to Replicate an Excel Array Formula in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to replicate an Excel Array Formula in DAX.  I am struggling to understand the correct context in which the formula needs to operate.  This is the problem.

| Category | Sub Category 2 | Location | Sales | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Sub Product 1 | Area 1 | 35 | 65% |
|  |  | Area 2 | 10 | 58% |
|  | Sub Product 2 | Area 1 | 15 | 75% |
|  |  | Area 2 | 21 | 65% |

At this level it works fine.  The Value column is assigned by a SUMX at area level and the sales is a SUMX of the sales column.

I am trying to report at category and sub category level and I don't seem to be able to work it out.  So instead of summing the Value I need to weight them and compress them down.  Averagex doesn't quite fit the bill as I need to weight the value at based on the sales.

If anyone can tell me how this is done I'd be very grateful.

Update
Apologies I'm finding it hard to articulate while keeping it quite anonymous.

Calculate the % of sales per area and use it to weight the Value

Value calc for line 1 = Sales / Total Sales for Sub Product 1

Calculation Table

| Category | Sub Category 2 | Sales | Value | Value Calc | Value Res |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Sub Product 1 | 35 | 65% | 0.7778 * .65 | .50557 |
|  |  | 10 | 58% | 0.2222 * .58 | .12876 |
| Value | Required | 45 |  |  | 63.43% |
|  | Sub Product 2 | 15 | 75% | 0.4166 * .75 | .31245 |
|  |  | 21 | 65% | 0.5833 * .65 | .379145 |
| Value | Required | 36 |  |  | 69.19% |

Result desired for sub product level

| Category | Sub Category 2 | Sales | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Sub Product 1 | 45 | 63.43% |
|  | Sub Product 2 | 36 | 69.19% |

Then go one level more down to Category

Value calc for line 1 = Sales / Total Sales Product 1

Calculation Table for Product

| Category | Sub Category 2 | Sales | Value | Value Calc | V Res |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Sub Product 1 | 45 | 63.43% | .556 * 63.43% | .352 |
|  | Sub Product 2 | 36 | 69.19% | .444 * 69.19% | .307 |
| Value | Result | 81 |  |  | 65.9% |

Result / desired result table

| Category | Sales | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 81 | 65.9% |

The Value field is stored in a field and I use the following

Value = SUMX(Table1, Value)

Sales = SUMX(Table2, Sales)

I've tried everything but I don't seem to be able to get the right answer.

Comment: Can you show how `Value` is calculated? I'm having a hard time understanding your output, can you give a more concrete example? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can I ask if this is clearer now I've added an update?

Comment: What is the expected result? Sum or Average of [Value Res] column?  In the first row, what is 0.7778? Do you have a special column for these values? Why have you presented column with sales? Do you need it to calculate your expected result?

Comment: Can you post a link to sample excel file with an array formula that works for you?

Comment: What do you weight the values with? How do you create table with weights? Weights are specific to which column(s)? Product? Sub category 2? What do you mean by 'compress them'? You mean sum of weighted values?

Comment: Is column Value given, or calculated? If calculated, then how do you get 65%, 58%, 75%... Where did you get 0.7778 from? I am guessing it is percentage by category over Subcategory2 column.

Comment: It would be best if you could explain step by step how you have calculated the last figure 65.9%. Down to source given columns with primary input values.

Comment: Ultimately I need a weighted average on the Value field so I can use it to calculate on.  The Value is stored at Area value level in the top table but my dashboard presents by year and can be filtered by Product and Sub Product. So as the report reports at a higher level instead of using the average I want to weight the average by sales amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that your data looks like this:

```
+----------+---------+-------+----------+
| Category | Country | Sales | Discount |
+----------+---------+-------+----------+
| Europe   | Albania |    35 |     0.65 |
| Europe   | UK      |    10 |     0.58 |
| America  | Mexico  |    15 |     0.75 |
| America  | Belize  |    21 |     0.65 |
+----------+---------+-------+----------+
```

It might be that this measure is what you are after:

```
SUMX(
    'Table',
    'Table'[Discount]
        * DIVIDE(
            'Table'[Sales],
            [Sales by Category]
        )
)
```

Where:

```
[Sales by Category] =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( table[Sales] ),
    REMOVEFILTERS ( table ),
    VALUES ( table[Category] )
)
```